# Render images of Openstreetmap regarding your position

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to show images for a certain position from Openstreetmap on my page, without rendering the map itself,Any ideas on how to do so ?
Informations: Experience with Openstreetmap : 0 months

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to just include an embedded map. For that go to http://www.openstreetmap.org, pan to your location, click on the "Share" tool of the sidebar on the right, an than use the "HTML" option to get HTML-code to embed in your website.

Comment: What if the location is dynamic ? Can I send a query to openstreet with the location data and get the images back ?

Comment: The HTML code contains a [bbox](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bounding_Box) inside the *iframe* as well as a link with *latitude* and *longitude* parameters (the last two numbers after *#map=*, the first number is the zoom level).